# Magento textbox custom validation

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, forms, form-validation

I Need a custom form validation in a textbox

The value should be like this `3-5`, so `<number>-<number>`

Please suggest me some ideas

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to your question?

Comment: no solution found this

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom Javascript validation for any form. Inchoo has [a post](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/) about that and Alan Storm also [wrote something](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/6579512188/magento-custom-form-validation) about it

After the form is initiated in your html, which would look something like `var theForm = new VarienForm('theForm', true);` add the following

```
Validation.add('validate-must-be-number-dash-number','Is not number-number!',function(the_field_value){
    if(the_field_value.match('/[0-9]-[0-9]/ig'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

So, in full; it would look something like this in your form phtml file

```
<form ... id="theForm">
   [...]
   <input type="text" class="input-text validate-must-be-number-dash-number" value=""/>
   [...]
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var theForm = new VarienForm('theForm', true);
Validation.add('validate-must-be-number-dash-number','Is not number-number!',function(the_field_value){
        if(the_field_value.match('/[0-9]-[0-9]/ig'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Now add the class `validate-must-be-number-dash-number` to your input and you're done

Comment: 3-5 example i need like that

Comment: I don't think I understand you, what is not ok about above example?

Comment: in this we can use 3-5 only right

Comment: That is correct, this checks if the value is `3-5`, you can alsways tweak it to check for another value. It's basic javascript, nothing fancy there

Comment: that's example i need that format not only 3-5

Comment: I've changed my answer to use a regex, but honestly, try to tweak it yourself as well. I'll try to give an as fitting as possible answer but some work from your side is still required

Comment: where i can use this js

Comment: I've updated my answer, more clear than this I'm afraid I cant make it

Comment: it's ok not working i will try