# How to add custom validation for admin form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2.2, php-7.1

I want to add custom validation in the text box in Magento 2.
How I can do it?

[image]

Comment: you can find `_prepareToRender` function and find column then add 
 'class' => 'validate-number validate-digits validate-greater-than-zero'

Comment: check this answer, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95171/magento-2-form-validation

Comment: You can do it with the help of jquery. Please refer to the following link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87984/magento-textbox-custom-validation

Answer (score 0):

check this answer, [Magento 2 - Form Validation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95171/magento-2-form-validation)

Answer (score 0):

> **Please use this in your form field.**

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

[For More Click Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/193982/82670)

[Add Custom Validation](https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-validation-rule-in-ui-component-form-field/)